# trouble with static const integral member declaration

Tags: c++, initialization, constants, static-members

I'm a little confused about static class/struct member declaration/initialization.

I was convinced that it's necessary declare a static member inside the class/struct body and initialize it outside. With an important exception: it's possible declare *and* initialize a static member inside the class/struct body if the member (a) is const and (b) is of integral type (`bool`, `int`, `long`, etc.).

So (I was convinced that) it's perfectly legal something like

```
struct foo
 { static const int i = 123; };
```

And it works, in the following example

```
#include <iostream>

struct foo
 {
   static const int i = 123;

   void baz (const int j)
    { std::cout << "baz: j = " << j << '\n'; }

   void bar ()
    { baz(foo::i); }
 };

int main ()
 {
   foo().bar();

   return 0;
 }
```

But if I change the definition of `foo::baz()` method passing the argument `j` as reference

```
   void baz (const int & j)
    { std::cout << "baz: j = " << j << '\n'; }
```

I find that `foo::i` is undefined. And this with `g++` (4.9.2), with `clang++` (3.5.0), compiling as c++98, as c++11 or as c++14. In all cases i get the following linker error: `riferimento non definito a "foo::i"` (italian for "undefined reference to \"`foo::i`\"").

If I declare only the static member inside

```
   //static const int i = 123;
   static const int i;
```

and initialize it outside the body of the struct,

```
const int foo::i = 123;
```

no more errors and the program work as expected.

So... why?

It's me (I don't understand the static member initialization?) or are the compilers (a bug of `g++` and `clang++`?)?

p.s.: sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Would there be any repercussions if you used `const int i = 123;` inside your structure? i.e., remove the `static` keyword?

Comment: @Logicrat: without `static`, no errors (only a couple of warning compiling with c++98 because only from c++11 you can initialize in this way a not static variable)

Comment: @David: I suppose you're right: the question is little different but the background is the same and the answer are good for my question too. What I'm supposed to do in this (duplicate question) case? I should delete the question?

Comment: @max66 You don't have to do anything, it's all good. Just leave your question here - it may be useful to someone in the future even marked as duplicate